# Redirect CloudPage to an Error Page

Tags: ampscript, cloudpage, landing-page, smart-capture

I have a Smart Capture form on my CloudPage for lead generation. The DE it fills is using `EmailAddress` as the primary key. If the user submitting the form already exists in the DE and they attempt to complete the form, I want to redirect the user to a different URL letting them know they are already subscribed.

Currently, if the user already exists, the form does not submit. The user doesn't know why and it's a bad UX. I think I can use AMPscript to do this, but am fairly new and not sure what the code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
%%[SET @emailaddress = RequestParameter("EmailAddress")
SET @isExsistingCustomeremail = Lookup("YourDE","EmailAddress",@emailaddress)

IF(@isExsistingCustomeremail) THEN
//Redirect user to the other url
ELSE
//Upsert the data in your DE]%%
 ENDIF
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful